# Eternal loop with expect

Tags: linux, expect

I want this expect script to run forever (or until "ok" is printed), however it does not and exits right away.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 180

spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@10.1.31.11
expect "password: "
send "[lindex $argv 1]\n"
expect "$ "

send { while true ;
do
   sleep 1s
   STRLIST=`echo pippo`
   [[ ${#STRLIST} -ge 20  ]] && echo ok && break
done
}
expect "ok"

send {echo Finished! }

send "exit\n"
```

It looks like that somehow the eternal loop goes on a separate thread, and after entering (and exiting) the loop nothing is printed at all.

EDIT: this is a simplified version of an actually useful script. The STRLIST content changes with every iteration and I want to exit the loop when a condition is fulfilled. Instead the script exit the loop immediately and I don't know why.

EDIT2: It looks like this is the issue:

expect: does " while true ;\r\n> do\r\n>    sleep 1s\r\n>    STRLIST=`echo pippo`\r\n>    [[ ${#STRLIST} -ge 20  ]] && echo ok && break\r\n> done\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ok"? yes

"ok" is contained within my own command.

Comment: No, it's an infinite loop that never prints anything. The length or  STRLIST will never be anything other than 5, so "ok" is never printed. What were you expecting to see?

Comment: The point is that script actually ends, and I don't know how to prevent that.

Comment: `set timeout -1` -- currently `expect "ok"` returns after 180 seconds.

Comment: Run the script with `expect -d script.exp` to see what's happening in the background.

Comment: The loop ends immediately. The timeout is unrelated

Comment: Add the `expect -d` debugging output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen finally, what you send to the spawned command is first echoed back. This is normal for a tty (your terminal), and is inherited by the pty created by `spawn`.

You can either remember to cope with this in your `expect` patterns, or simply switch this echoing off if it is not useful. Do this **before** the `spawn` by setting the global variable `stty_init`:

```
set stty_init -echo
```

Or you can do this at a later time, before a `send` you do not want echoed, by using the `stty` command on the pty:

```
stty -echo < $spawn_out(slave,name)
```

(Note the spaces around `<`). Obviously, this allows you to set the echo back on similarly.